# Creating a layout in Rebol

Tags: user-interface, rebol, red

I am trying to create a layout to be shown by view in the manner described in answer by @GrahamChiu on [REBOL layout: How to create layout words automatically - word has no context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37431247/rebol-layout-how-to-create-layout-words-automatically-word-has-no-context) :

```
REBOL []

; WANT TO CREATE A BLOCK: [across chvar: check label "test"] , so that I can run: 
; view layout [across chvar: check label "test"]

toappend: [across (to-set-word "chvar") 'check 'label "test" ]
probe toappend

mylist: []
foreach i toappend [append mylist i]
probe mylist

view layout mylist
```

I later want to create a loop to add many such sets to layout.

The `probe` output is:

```
[across (to-set-word "chvar") 'check 'label "test"]
[across to-set-word "chvar" check label "test"]
```

However, the "chvar" is not getting set to `chvar:` and I am getting following error:

```
Invalid args: [to-set-word "chvar" check label "test"]
```

Apparently, `(to-set-word "chvar")` is not getting evaluated before being appended. How can this be corrected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot **compose**

For Red

```
toappend:  compose [across (to-set-word "chvar") check text "test" ]
mylist: []
foreach i toappend [append mylist i]
view layout mylist
```

as Red does not know label, otherwise same as in Rebol